# Окно выбора в Android

Tags: android

Как называется окно в Android, при нажатии на которое открывается окно выбора чего-либо?
Наподобие пикера.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется [Диалоговое окно AlertDialog (клик)](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/alertdialog.php) .